# Progress Bar React Component

Tags: javascript, react.js

Here is the code to a progress bar component. Is there anything that you feel I should improve to it?

If I state that the progress prop is required, is it ok NOT to check in the code that progress is not null?

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default function ProgressBar({ progress, progressBarColor }) {
  const percentage = progress > 1 ? 100 : progress * 100;
  const commonStyles = 'rounded-50 h-13 lg:h-9 lgx:h-12 xl:h-13';

  return (
    <div className={`bg-grey-light relative overflow-hidden ${commonStyles}`}>
      <div className={`${progressBarColor} ${commonStyles}`} style={{ width:`${percentage}%` }}>
        &nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ProgressBar.propTypes = {
  progress: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  progressBarColor: PropTypes.string
};

ProgressBar.defaultProps = {
  progressBarColor: 'bg-gradient-b-turquoise-cyan'
};
```

I would use this progress bar to display the usage of some resource for example. Once that usage reaches a certain percentage, I would need to change the bar's color to orange for example and make it read if you have reached the limit/the maximum usage of the resource.

```
render() {     
  let progressBarColor = 'bg-gradient-b-turquoise-cyan';
  if (progress >= 1) {
    progressBarColor = 'bg-red';
  } else if (progress >= 0.8) {
    progressBarColor = 'bg-orange';
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ProgressBar
        progress={progress}
        progressBarColor={progressBarColor}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Don't hesitate to comment on why you are downgrading the question? I am looking forward to discussing about code with the community :) Maybe explain how would you ask the question?

Comment: I can only guess at the downvoter's motivation by looking at the close votes. They say "the description lacks context". Maybe they wanted to see some code that actually uses this progress bar, and a little description of where you intend to use it.

Comment: I have now added the code that uses the progress bar and the little description explaining the usage.